# MS CRM Data Import issues while mapping record GUID

Tags: dynamics-crm, on-premises-instances

Trying to import the records in to CRM on-premise environment (8.2) version.
Need to create new contact records with the GUID mapping to the unique id. Exporting the data from another environment. The issue is when I am tried first time to import it using the outbox import wizard it is showing successfully imported all the records. But in the data base the records are not exists. Out of 10000 only 20 to 30 records are exists.

Next time when I tried the import wizard with same input file it is giving “Generic Sql error”.
For those 20 to 30 records which was created during the first import giving the duplicate error.

Then I tried using the SSIS package. But it is not working giving “Generic SQL error”.
When I am removing the record GUID the records are importing but with GUID it is giving generic SQL error.

Comment: It sounds like you get the error when you try to create a record with an existing Guid (as you should). Why it only creates a few records is another question that there is not enough information here to really answer.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my questions now. I trying to create new record with guid which is not exists in the destination environment.

Comment: Well, they do exist after the first import, which is why they give you an error on second try.

Comment: But only I can find around 30 records in CRM. Other records are not exits. Even i searched in the database also with GUID.

Comment: Yes, and as I said, that part I cannot help you with based on just the information given. You may need to see if there is an error hiding somewhere that did not bubble up to CRM (places to look could be the Windows event log on both the CRM and the SQL servers)

Comment: can you try in small batches and see, also save it as csv and import in OOB import. Verify if you have any plugins/workflow on create, check in plugin trace log or in system jobs.

Comment: Disabled all the workflow which is running on create. Only the Activity Feed plugin is running. Tried with 5 and 6 records. Still the same issues.